# using double (*input)[2] for fftw complex numbers

Tags: casting, fftw

fftw_complex is the type fftw library uses for inputs and outputs. http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html

can I simply use `double (*input)[2]=new double [length][2];`and then cast it into fftw_complex ? Would there be any incompatibility?

This would be good to know because if there would be incompatibility that would mean I'd need to create a new array of fftw_complex and copy everything to it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it like this:

```
double (*input)[2] = new double [length][2];
fftw_complex* data;
data = input;
```

С++ type system don't distinguish type and his typedef alias.
Function of typedef is only making type names more readable.